# Laravel не работают параметры (id) у route::resource

Tags: php, laravel

Писал CRUD для своего приложения и заметил странное поведение `Route::resource`

У меня есть группа, в которую вложена другая группа. И во второй группе у меня ресурсный роут с name = '/'. Но ему нельзя передать в методы `edit`, `delete` и тд параметр `$id`. При этом, если вынести его из второй группы в первую, изменить name на любой, то всё работает

```js
// DON'T WORK
Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->as('admin.')->group(function() {
  
  Route::prefix('parts/')->as('parts.')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('/', AdminPartController::class)->names('');
  });
});

// WORK
Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->as('admin.')->group(function() {
  
    Route::resource('/parts', AdminPartController::class)->names('parts');
});
```

Comment: Я вынес `resource` из группы и добавил ему name. Так работает. Возможно, это из-за того, что нет name?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать следующим образом:

```
Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function() {  
  Route::prefix('parts')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('/', AdminPartController::class)->names('parts');
  });
});
```

Comment: Да, я тоже так пробовал - тоже не выходит. `route:list` выдаёт следующее: `GET|HEAD        admin/parts/{}/edit .... admin.parts.edit › Admin\PartController@edit`

Comment: А если писать `Route::resource('/parts'...`, То вместо {} подставляется {part}. То есть работает